# How to estimate distribution via transition probability in MCMC

Tags: markov-chains, sampling

In the chapter 11 of PRML, equation 11.73. The equation is trying to use samples obtained from Markov chain to define the important-sampling distribution.

$$
P_G(z) = \frac{1}{Z_G}exp(-G(z)) = \frac{1}{L}\sum^L_{l=1}T(z^{(l)},z)
$$
where $T(z,z')$ is the transition markov chain probability, and the sample set is given by $z^{(1)},...,z^{(L)},$

According to Markov chain, a distribution is said to be invariant if
$$
p(x) = \sum_{x'} T(x',x)p(x')
$$

But I don't understand why sum of transition probability could use for estimation of proposed probability. Is there any proof or relevant theorem?

Answer (score 1):

In the invariant expression,
$$p(x) = \sum_{x'} T(x', x)p(x')$$
we can think that $p(x)$ is the average value of $T(x', x)$ according to the probability $p(x')$. That is,
$$p(x) = \sum_{x'} T(x', x)p(x') \approx \frac{1}{L}\sum_{l=1}^{L}T(x'^{(l)},x) \,.$$
So, we can get the desired result by $p(x) = P_G(x)$.

Comment: Do you consider this to be a proof? Do you know of any relevant theorem?

Comment: This is related to the well known theorem, [Law of Large Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law).